# Ecto: how to call a function in an update

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to create a migration that converts the data in a column to a different format by calling the function `date_str_to_timestamp` (which is defined in the same file) on every item in that column.

```
from(p in "posts",
     update: [set: [ timestamp: ^date_str_to_timestamp(p.time) ]])
|> Pesterbot.Repo.update_all([])
```

However I get this:

```
 _build/dev/lib/pesterbot/priv/repo/migrations/20170414014413_posts_to_messages.exs:34

** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `^(p.time(), date_str_to_timestamp)` is not a valid query expression.

* If you intended to call a database function, please check the documentation
  for Ecto.Query to see the supported database expressions

* If you intended to call an Elixir function or introduce a value,
  you need to explicitly interpolate it with ^

    (ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.update/3
    _build/dev/lib/pesterbot/priv/repo/migrations/20170414014413_posts_to_messages.exs:33: Pesterbot.Repo.Migrations.PostsToMessages.up/0
    (ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.from/2
    _build/dev/lib/pesterbot/priv/repo/migrations/20170414014413_posts_to_messages.exs:33: Pesterbot.Repo.Migrations.PostsToMessages.up/0
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.|>/2
    _build/dev/lib/pesterbot/priv/repo/migrations/20170414014413_posts_to_messages.exs:35: Pesterbot.Repo.Migrations.PostsToMessages.up/0
```

edit: source of `date_str_to_timestamp` as requested by @Dogbert

```
def date_str_to_timestamp(date_str) do
    {:ok, datetime} = Timex.parse(date_str, "{UNIX}")
    datetime |> Elixir.DateTime.to_unix(:millisecond)
  end
end
```

edit: 
`timestamp` is going to be an integer of milliseconds since epoch of the corresponding `time` value, which is right now a UNIX formatted string eg: `Mon Mar 20 19:49:43 CDT 2017`

so `Mon Mar 20 19:49:43 CDT 2017` should become `1490057383000`

Comment: You cannot call an Elixir function in an UPDATE query like that since database must be able to evaluate the expression itself. If you post the source of that function, we may be able to find an equivalent function in PostgreSQL.

Comment: updated, from a quick perusal it looks like no...

how would I got about transforming this data then? query for it, manually change it, and then update based on id?

Comment: Oh, I thought `{UNIX}` is a Unix Timestamp. Try this: `[set: [timestamp: fragment("?::timestamp", p.time)]]`. If this doesn't work, can you post the database types of the `time` and `timestamp` fields? (`\d tablename` from `psql` should print that)

Comment: updated, how do I test these out in a psql shell?

Comment: Does the answer I posted work for you?

Comment: yes, it's perfect! I'm trying to figure out how to go the opposite way for my `down` function now...

Comment: Opposite way? What did the field have before? This will overwrite whatever the old value was.

Comment: It's alright, I figured it out. For those who are curious: when doing an `ecto` migration you have to write a `down` that undoes what you do in `up`, so the opposite of turning a UNIX date string into a timestamp is turning the timestamp into the UNIX date string: `[set: [time: fragment("to_char(to_timestamp(?), 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZ YYYY')", p.timestamp)]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call an Elixir function in an `UPDATE` query like that since database must be able to evaluate the expression itself. Fortunately, PostgreSQL does have functions to do what your Elixir function does:

```
iex(1)> A.date_str_to_timestamp "Tue Mar 5 23:25:19 PST 2013"
1362554719000
```

```
postgres=# select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM 'Tue Mar 5 23:25:19 PST 2013'::timestamp) * 1000;
   ?column?
---------------
 1362525919000
(1 row)
```

You can use this in an `UPDATE` query like this:

```
from(p in "posts",
     update: [set: [timestamp: fragment("EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ?::timestamp) * 1000", p.time)]])
```